# What was so bad about Nathan's video logs?

Tags: ex-machina

Ex-Machina plot spoilers ahead, friends.

> Caleb gains entry to Nathan's room and uses his computer to view video logs of Nathan creating the previous AI attempts. This seems to shock and disgust Caleb and makes him realize that, in his mind, Nathan really is a bad guy.

Why does this spark a change in Caleb? I feel like I've missed something here. Caleb seems taken aback by this. Was Nathan doing something wrong that I missed? It seemed to me that he was just working on the robots. It wasn't pretty for sure, but if you're going to create life, you're bound to make some mistakes

Did I miss some obvious wrong-doing or was this simply a culmination of

> the psychological manipulation Ava was playing on him the whole time?

Comment: They're *not* robots; they're people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I remember the movie correctly, Caleb is taken aback because he has already started empathizing with Ava, and seeing Nathan disassembling or discarding his previous attempts feels to him as if Nathan were doing it to sentient beings, treating them as if they were machines. So I think the video logs make him fear for Ava's future once the experiment is over.

I think the following dialogue between Nathan and Caleb shows the latter's state of mind:

> **Caleb**: "I didn't know there was gonna be a model after Ava."
>
> **Nathan**: "Yeah, why? You thought she was a one-off?"
>
> **Caleb**: "No, I knew there must have been prototypes. So I... I knew she wasn't the first, but I thought maybe the last."
>
> **Nathan**: "Well, Ava doesn't exist in isolation any more than you or me. She's part of a continuum. So Version 9.6 and so on. And each time they get a little bit better."
>
> **Caleb**: "When you make a new model, what do you do with the old one?"
>
> **Nathan**: "Well, I, uh... download the mind, unpack the data. Add in the new routines I've been writing. And to do that you end up partially formatting, so the memories go. But the body survives. And Ava's body is a good one. You feel bad for Ava?"

Comment: I guess my view that wiping her memory isn't killing her was clouding my judgement a bit. After all, she IS better than her previous versions. We should all be so lucky. I digress lol